# PHP mail form is not working

Tags: php, forms, email

I m having a problem with my email php form, when I click in the submit button an other page shows up saying `There was a problem with your e-mail ()`
I don't no what I am doing wrong?

here is my code:

html code

```
<!-- Subscription Form -->
  <form class="email" action="form.php" method="post">
    <input class="get_notified" type="text" placeholder="Enter your email address ..."/>
    <button type="submit" class="go" /></form>
<!-- End Subscription Form -->

    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

php code

```
<?php
$to = "email@mydomain.com";
$from = "email@mydomain.com";

$headers = "From: " . $from . "\r\n";

$subject = "New subscription";
$body = "New user subscription: " . $_POST['email'];


if( filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) )
{ 
if (mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers, "-f " . $from))
{
    echo 'Your e-mail (' . $_POST['email'] . ') has been added to our mailing list!';
}
else
{
   echo 'There was a problem with your e-mail (' . $_POST['email'] . ')';   
}
}
else
{
echo 'There was a problem with your e-mail (' . $_POST['email'] . ')';   
}
```

Comment: The two error messages in your code are exactly the same, so you wouldn't know which `else` block triggered it. Change one of the messages to something different to find out which condition evaluates to false.

Comment: Try reducing the amount of codes to only the mail function and see if it works, if it does, start adding your codes bit by bit

Comment: Dulax has provided you with the reason the code does not work, add the name attribute to your form field

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to add a `name="email"` field to your HTML form in order for PHP to be able to fetch it using `$_POST['email']`

```
<input class="get_notified" name="email" type="text" placeholder="Enter your email address ..."/>
```